# Error 1004 renaming worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I keep having troubles with "Error 1004 - Method 'Name' of object '_Worksheet'" in my VBA macro.
Basically the idea of this macro is to check the cells of a column (containing strings) and to compare them to the names of the worksheets of my workbook.
If there is a cell whose value doesn't appear among the names of the worksheets, the macro should create a new worksheet and rename it after the value inside the cell.

```
    For j = (RowStart + 1) To 500

    'allocate the value of the reference cell in cell_content
    cell_content = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(j, ColStart).Value
    Switch = 0    

    'check if cell_content appears as the name of one of the worksheet
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If cell_content = Sheets(i).Name Then
            Switch = Switch + 1
        End If
    Next i

    'if it does not, the macro creates a new worksheets with the name of cell_content
    If Switch = 0 Then
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
            ws.Name = cell_content
    End If        
Next j
```

Consider that ColStart and RowStart are just the reference values for the column under consideration and the variable Switch is used to define whether or not it is required to create a new worksheet.

The problem is that the very last part of the macro keeps giving me error 1004.
Does anyone know what can be the problem?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your workbook is locked. A small code like this works on an empty Excel:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "CodeThatWorks"    
End Sub
```

What may be the other possible reason that your code does not work is that the name is like this `ws.Name = "BadNamesIncludeThese:]\?*[]"`, thus including special characters which are not allowed for a name in the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks man, I tried the code you gave me and it worked (of course). I also tried to adapt it to my case (keeping it simple) and it still worked, so I changed my actual macro using your suggestion and it now gives "run-time error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error". Any idea?

Comment: @AndreaM. - how many worksheets with the name "CodeThatWorks" do you have? If it is 1, it cannot work.

Comment: No it's more. I changed it, referring to a column containing the followings: string1, string2, string3, string4. Then I iterated your code in order to create 4 worksheets with these names and it worked. But when I tried to do the same on my actual macro, it gave me that error. The names I'm using are different one from the other, since I know that each worksheet has to have a different name from the others.

Comment: @AndreaM. - are you sure that the workbook is not locked for editing?

Comment: I don't think so, because now it seems it's working. I'm basically starting from your working module and adding more complex features, trying to get to my original macro.
I'm trying to see whethe point from which it starts giving me the error. Just hope it works

Comment: @AndreaM. - have you tried debugging with F8? It should be about 5 minute job.

Comment: Damn, I think I understood the error. The macro probably goes on blank cells and tries to rename the worksheet after those. I put an if cycle with the scope of avoiding that, but I think it doesn't work. I'm now working on it